# Why doesn't electric-indent-mode indent in comments?

Tags: indentation, major-mode

I've defined my own major mode using `define-generic-mode`, and in the setup function I have `(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'my-indent-function)`.

This works fine in general code, however it is not called at all when I'm inside a comment, as defined by the syntax table with:

```el
;; // Comments (style a)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\/ ". 124" (syntax-table))
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> " (syntax-table))
;; /* Comments (style b) */
(modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23b" (syntax-table))
```

*Either `// line comments` or `/* Java comments */` are allowed.*

I've tried setting `comment-line-break-function` as I saw that it is set in Java mode, but this doesn't have any effect. I also tried setting `comment-indent-function` to `nil`, but again I couldn't see any effect.

EDIT: Added example minimal repro.

To test, just run `emacs -Q`, paste the following into a buffer and run `eval-buffer`, then open `test.tmp`. Every time you hit return not inside a comment you will see "Called indent-line!" in the mini-buffer. Inside a comment you will not. This is my question.

```el
(define-generic-mode
    tmp-mode ; mode name

  ;; comments
  nil

  ;; keywords
  '("if" "then" "else")

  ;; other things to highlight
  nil

  ;; auto mode alist
  '("\\.tmp?$")

  ;; other function to run
  (list 'tmp-mode--setup-function)
  "A mode for tmp files")

(defun tmp-mode--setup-function ()
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (syntax-table))
  ;; // Comments (style a)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\/ ". 124" (syntax-table))
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> " (syntax-table))
  ;; /* Comments (style b) */
  (modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23b" (syntax-table))
  (modify-syntax-entry ?@ "_" (syntax-table))

  (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'tmp-mode/indent-line))

(defun tmp-mode/indent-line ()
  (message "Called indent-line!"))

(provide 'tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

May reproduce your problem meanwhile - answer edited. While without `electric-indent-mode` `indent-according-to-mode` would call `indent-line-function`- if `electric-indent-mode` is on, no indent any more. IIUC it's worth a bug-report.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw, but I defined my own indentation function as this is my own major mode. The indentation function is not called on newline at all inside comments when in `electric-indent-mode`, while every other newline does.

Comment: @meatherway Maybe post your indent-function, so we can have a look?

Comment: The trouble is that the indent-function is never even being called. I will update with a minimal repro major-mode tomorrow morning.

Comment: Right, I've added a repro